# For eclipse PDT which php.ini is it picking up for PHP scripts

Tags: php, eclipse, curl

I can not get the Eclipse PDT to pull in the curl library. If I run it by command line it is fine. From the logs I see that the PHP command that eclipse launches uses a temp PHP.ini file found in /tmp/zend_debug/session9211448873864684697.tmp/php.ini
Using phpinfo() I see that curl is not there so I'm assuming that it is not picking up the extra ini files found in conf.d/ How can I get access to the php.ini file eclipse uses.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This actually is a bug in eclipse, I reported it here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=347618

And a workaround is just to concatenate all your included ini-files into one for eclipse, like suggested here: [While I am debugging PHP Script in Eclipse, it doesn't load mysql extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784327/while-i-am-debugging-php-script-in-eclipse-it-doesnt-load-mysql-extension/6163018#6163018)

Hope this helps.