# phpunit ignores /etc/php5/cli/conf.d directory on startup when launched from within eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, phpunit, php-ini

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [While I am debugging PHP Script in Eclipse, it doesn’t load mysql extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784327/while-i-am-debugging-php-script-in-eclipse-it-doesnt-load-mysql-extension)

**How can I make phpunit scan the    /etc/php5/cli/conf.d  directory for ini files?**

I am using phpunit, but it is very time-consuming to configure correctly. One issue I just encountered is that ini files for my php extensions do not seem to get loaded properly, when I Lauch phpunit as a "Run Configuration" from within Eclipse.
I basically followed this tutorial: http://pkp.sfu.ca/wiki/index.php/Configure_Eclipse_for_PHPUnit

When run from within eclipse (Menu Run.../Run Configurations...), then
the directory

```
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d
```

which is linked to

```
/etc/php5/conf.d/
```

is not parsed.
Thus, for example, file

```
/etc/php5/conf.d/curl.ini
```

is ignored.
I have to add the one-liner to the ini file

```
 echo "extension=curl.so" >> /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

which seems to solve the problem, but it is counterproductive, because it breaks modularization (and will be gone after the next distri / php upgrade)

To find this issue, I modified phpunit.php
by adding a call to phpinfo() to the beginning of the file.

Here's the output.

```
PHP Version => 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4

System => Linux wb3 3.2.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Fri Sep 7 16:16:45 UTC 2012 x86_64
Build Date => Sep 12 2012 18:58:31
Server API => Command Line Interface
Virtual Directory Support => disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File => /tmp/zend_debug/session6700026373526677062.tmp/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => (none)
Additional .ini files parsed => (none)
```

When I inspect /tmp/zend_debug/session6700026373526677062.tmp/php.ini:

using
 grep -C 2 extension

I got no output.

After adding extension=curl.so to /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
the curl extension is loaded when I run the phpunit Eclipse-Run-configuration

But the result is different when I run phpunit from the command line.
Now I get

```
phpunit --debug --verbose  MyClass 
PHP Warning:  Module 'curl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

**Update: (no answers yet)**

I found a workaround for my problem:

I created a custom php.ini file in the filesystem, that contains all includes appended, and within Eclipse Preferences for PHP, I create a new configuration for  the  php5 interpreter, using my special-purpose php.ini.

Within Eclipse Run-Configuration Menu, , setting the Config Dialog Box, I simply point to the new php5-configuration.

But this does not solve the problem, so I'm still looking for answers. Is it an eclipse problem or a phpunit - problem? I have no clue at this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an expected behavior of Eclipse PDT. For more information, see [the similar question and my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784327/while-i-am-debugging-php-script-in-eclipse-it-doesnt-load-mysql-extension/6393850#6393850).

Comment: thanks. seems that my workaround is the only solution to this issue. in the eclipse bug reports (discovered by you), several other people have mentioned this trick.