# Makegood: Class 'Memcache' not found when exeuction PHPUnit

Tags: eclipse-plugin, phpunit, makegood

I want to use MakeGood[1] for executing PHPUnit-Tests within my eclipse. Local PHPUnit-setup is done, I can execute tests successfully.

But when starting a PHPUnit-Test via MakeGood, it stopps at

```
new Memcache();
```

where "Memcache" is the pecl-extension. Error message is "Fatal error: Class 'Memcache' not found".

How can I get the test in MakeGood running?

[1] http://piece-framework.com/projects/makegood

Comment: This is an expected behavior of Eclipse PDT. For more information, see [the similar question and my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784327/while-i-am-debugging-php-script-in-eclipse-it-doesnt-load-mysql-extension/6393850#6393850).

Answer (score 1):

You are using the internal PEAR library and there is no MemCache installed. You have to create a User Library with your PEAR folder as source. For more details [see this page](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/help/html/editing_php_user_libraries.htm).